# what is the structure of meta-object set(MOS) metanode?

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I am not very much familiar with ZFS file system.
I want to know the structure of meta-object set(MOS) metanode.

Comment: Is there any tool which recover deleted files from zfs file system ?

Answer (score 1):

Even people very familiar with ZFS are likely unaware of what the MOS is. I'm afraid your best bet is to look at these [specifications](http://www.giis.co.in/Zfs_ondiskformat.pdf) or the ZFS [source code](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/af3e10e5a78d3af8cef6088748978c6c612757f0/sys/cddl/contrib/opensolaris/uts/common/fs/zfs).

Comment: Thank you for this. But I am unable to reach the data.

Comment: What data are you unable to reach ?

Comment: I am trying to find my files in zfs drive. Is there any signature of meta-object set(MOS) metanode.

Comment: Can you import the pool?

Comment: Yes, I import the pool. I found the uber block , but after this what is way to reach to the data. How to link between uber block and data.

Comment: Here are some links that might be useful: http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=980 , http://www.eall.com.br/blog/?page_id=588 and https://blogs.oracle.com/video/entry/examining_zfs_on_disk_format

Comment: In any case, if you can import a pool, you can access its data in whatever dataset it resides through the regular file system access or raw device commands.

Comment: How we can reach from Object ID(NV list) to File data ?

Answer (score 0):

The MOS is just another dataset, but hidden from users. Is there something specific that you'd like to know? You can view various parts of the MOS using zdb. I suggest playing with the options of that tool to see the sort of data that is stored there.

Comment: I want to find the data in the disk manually, I opened my disk in hex editor.

Comment: That might be tough. I'd start by looking at the zfs on-disk format documents. You can find links to it from [http://open-zfs.org/wiki/Developer_resources] (the zfs wiki), but it'll be easier to use zdb to examine it, as that tool does all of the hard work.

To get you started: each disk in the pool has a "vdev label", in which is the uberblock ring. The uberblock with the latest txg has a blockpointer to the pool, which contains the MOS.

Good luck!

Comment: What is latest txg means here, and how to reach from blockpointer to the MOS?

Comment: txg = transaction group. In the uberblock ring, you'll find entries with different txgs. The latest one is the one with the largest value. The associated blockpointer will point to the first block of the pool. This is all in the on-disk format documents that I linked to above.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I want to know that ,                                                                            how can we recover deleted files from zfs file system ?